# Return INT Stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I receive error 1318 when I call this procedure in MYSQL. What am I doing wrong with this stored procedure? Am I even allowed to do something like this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `CN_renumber`
      (
    OUT @maxCn,
    OUT param1 INT,
    OUT update_count INT
      )
BEGIN

    DECLARE sql_error TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET sql_error = TRUE;
    START TRANSACTION;
    /*Renumber Cn in DBO*/
    /* Set max cn and incremented afterwords */
    SET @maxCn = '23206';
    UPDATE dbo.billadr SET Cn = (@maxCn:=@maxCn + 1);
    IF sql_error = FALSE THEN SET update_count = 1;
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        SET update_count = 0;
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
    END
```

Comment: What is this `OUT @maxCn,` ?

Comment: How do you call the procedure?

Comment: I call it in MYSQL using CALL test.CN_renumber;

Comment: One more note: in case of error in the UPDATE statement, the following code won't be executed.

Comment: @maxCn, is a variable so I can renumber the customer number.

Comment: @user2132252 Do not use session variables in paramater definition (@maxCn). Use all parameters when you call the procedure.

Comment: I took the session variable in the parameter definition out. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with parameters. Try this procedure, it will fix error 1318 -

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE CN_renumber
  (OUT maxCn int, OUT param1 int, OUT update_count int)
BEGIN

  SET @maxCn = 23206;
  UPDATE billadr SET Cn = (@maxCn := @maxCn + 1);

  SET maxCn = @maxCn;
END
```

Usage example -

```
SET @maxCn = NULL;
SET @param1 = NULL;
SET @update_count = NULL;
CALL CN_renumber(@maxCn, @param1, @update_count);

SELECT @maxCn, @param1, @update_count;
```

Comment: Thank You so very much! That's similar to the begining stored procedure code I began with. What I am trying to do now with the above code is to have the computer tell me if the code was executed successfull by returning a 0. Is it possible to do something similar to the above code?

Comment: One more link with examples - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resignal.html